# Keep original spacing while doing replacements [AWK, SED, GREP, ...]

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have two files which content are:

File 1:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEU     1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  1.00      PROT
```

File 2:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  2.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  5.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEUUUU  1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  3.00      PROT
```

The desired output file would be:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  5.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEUUUU  1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  1.00      PROT
```

I want to replace the content of the 10th column of file 2 with the content of 10th column in file 1

My first try was:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$10;next}{$10=a[FNR]}1' file1 file2
```

But the tabbed file that I get, the program that I am using to read it, it does not read it in tabbed form.

Then, I tried:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$10;next}{$10=a[FNR]}1' file1 file2
```

And the program does not read it neither.

So... I need to keep the original spacing.

***Any suggestion?***

Comment: do i understand you correctly? in the original file there are tabs but they get replaced with spaces

Comment: @db429 the original file have spaces but not tabs

Comment: okay. this might have confused me `But the tabbed file that I get, the program that I am using to read it, it does not read it in tabbed form.`

Comment: @db429 the file that I want to get, I will use it in an specialized software... but, that software does not read the obtained file with tabs... only read it with files with spacing given in the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is largely inspired from Ed Morton answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203066/column-replacement-with-awk-with-retaining-the-format

Using GNU awk (gawk) you can run: gawk -f my.awk file2.txt file1.txt, with my.awk being:

```
NR==FNR { pdb[NR]=$0; next }
{
split(pdb[FNR],flds,FS,seps)
flds[10]=$10
for (i=1;i in flds;i++)
printf "%s%s", flds[i], seps[i]
print ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The solution:**

`awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="61 1:4 1:10" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' file1 file2`

**The process to the solution:**

Since awk removes all but one space characters I thought about a way how to include these spaces and define fixed widths for the columns named `fields` in awk.
And here comes the `FIELDWIDTHS` option, as is explained in the [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size) manual:

> The splitting of an input record into fixed-width fields is specified
> by assigning a string containing space-separated numbers to the
> built-in variable FIELDWIDTHS. Each number specifies the width of the
> field, including columns between fields.

So at first I came up with: `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 3 4 8 6 8 9 8 6 10 4" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$10;next}{$10=a[FNR]}1' file1 file2` but the output adds a space (NewField-character) infront of all fields starting with the second one. So I tried around with skipping one character with adding `:1` infront of all but the first field definitions, but this did not have the effect I wanted - actually it made things worse.

But since there is only one specified field that needs editing, I thought why not seperate the file in only three fields so I came up with:
`awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="62 4 10" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' file1 file2` but again there are those extra space characters. So I substracted 1 from the length of the first field and used `1:` to skip one character for the following fields.

This seems **awk**ward but gives the desired output ;)

P.S: While testing i used `meld` (a graphical diff application) to compare the output - which i wrote to file3 by adding  `> file3` to the end of the command - with file2.

Comment: can you explain it?